# What does running nmap on a server reveal about your computer?

Tags: nmap

If you run the `nmap` command on a server eg. `nmap espn.com` or `nmap -Pn espn.com` what information does that reveal to the server about you (eg. ip address or MAC address)? Does using a private vpn reduce what is revealed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does reveal your IP address, but not your MAC address. Using a private VPN makes the scan appear as if it is originating from the VPN's public IP address, rather than your personal public IP address.